# remote debugging debug (VS2010 c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, remote-debugging

To debug a C# application remotely I attach to the process using the remote debuggin monitor.

Debugging works fine except that I haven't found a way to read the Console.WriteLine() on my local machine. Anyway to get the console Output transfered?

Or any other way to easily write debug message which I can tail on my local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx).